# php mysql prevent duplicate inserts from rapid form submits

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm testing with this code:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');

if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {

  $r = $db->query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE value="'.$_POST['value'].'"');
  $n = $r->rowCount();

  for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
    // do nothing
  }

  if  (!$n) {
    $db->query('INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (NULL, "'.$_POST['value'].'")');
  }

}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="value" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When testing the above form in safari I am able to submit the same value into my database multiple times by rapidly clicking the submit button.

But, when I test with this code:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');

if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {

  for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
    // do nothing
  }

  $r = $db->query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE value="'.$_POST['value'].'"');
  $n = $r->rowCount();

  if  (!$n) {
    $db->query('INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (NULL, "'.$_POST['value'].'")');
  }

}
?>
```

The conditional works and I'm unable to submit the same value multiple times no matter how fast I click the submit button.

Is there a reliable way to prevent duplicate database inserts from occurring with the first code snippet so that it behaves just like the second snippet?

Comment: If you don't want the same value to be in multiple rows on a table, you should set it up with an unique constraint in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally a client side `onsubmit` handler can help stop accidental rapid-submissions, but I usually opt for a server side solution using `_SESSION` variables. Just create a hash of the `$_POST` array, store it as a session variable, and then compare the next submitted `_POST` to the hashed version:

```
session_start();
//if this is the first time they've posted, just create a placeholder session var
if (!isset($_SESSION['repost_hash'])){$_SESSION['repost_hash']="";}

//if the post array is a duplicate, nullify the submission
if (isset($_POST) && md5(serialize($_POST)) == $_SESSION['repost_hash']){ 
   unset($_POST);
} else { //otherwise, if this is new data, update the stored hash
   $_SESSION['repost_hash'] = md5(serialize($_POST));
}
...
```

If you only want to stop repeat-submissions for a short period of time, you can also have a second `$_SESSION` variable store the time of the last hash, so you can expire it after a second or two.